# Delete cells from Excel via VBA

Tags: excel

I am using the below code to delete all data from A13 to "Last row" in Col A.

```
Dim lastRowA As Long
With Application
  .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  .ScreenUpdating = False
   lastRowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("A13:A" & lastRowA).Select

   For i = Selection.Rows.Count To 13 Step -1
      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
          Selection.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
      End If
   Next i
  .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
  .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
```

It is clearing the values as expected. However, it is not DELETING these rows. i.e. I can still scroll down to row # 10000 (via scrollbar) even though there is no data in those cells. However, the last row that has data in my cell is Row# 12.

If I select all these cells, right click and delete these rows + Save the worksheet, I no longer have access (via scroolbar) to the 10000th row. This is what I am trying to achieve through VBA.

Clearly the code I have used is not doing a clean delete of the rows for some reason. Kindly help!

Comment: Unclear what the problem is?  You can always scroll down to the end of the sheet (row 1million+), regardless of what is or isn't on the sheet.

Comment: Ok sorry for being unclear. Let me try to explain. I first populate say 10,000 rows of Col A with values. Note that at this point, the scroll bar becomes tiny... obviously due to the large amount of scrolling to be done inorder to reach my last cell A10000. Then, I clear the range A13:A10000 using the mentioned code. It clears off the value. However, my scrollbar does not come back to the normal size. It is still that teeny tiny version that was there when I had 10K + rows populated... even though I now have just 12 rows with values throughout the sheet. Hope I made my problem clear.

Comment: Clear enough but what's the real problem?  You don't like the small scrollbar?  If you save and close the file and then reopen it, is the scrollbar back to how it was to begin with?  There's nothing you're missing when you delete your rows - that's how we all would do it more or less.

Comment: Once the query 'deletes' the rows... even if I save, close and reopen, the scrollbar remains tiny. Only way I can get back to the original scrollbar size is by selecting the rows from A13 to A10000, right click, delete it and save the file.

Comment: You say it yourself, when you do it manually, you save the workbook. You need to do the same in your code if you expect the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right and you want to delete all data from range `A13` where there is nothing in column "A", you can try:

```
Sub delete()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("A13:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.delete
        On Error GoTo 0
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Make sure you do a copy of your file before in case something goes wrong.
Note this is expected to be run on the activesheet.