# VBA script to delete unknown cells without selecting it firstly

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with a very long set of rows and columns. I'm looking for a VBA script to delete the content from cell A3 until the end of the last used row on column J.
Note that the table has more columns and I want to avoid to scroll until the very end and select the cells to delete content beforehand.

Couldn't really find a solution yet.

Comment: Mnay examples on here, see this and edit to suit; https://stackoverflow.com/q/53698132/4961700

Comment: Not what you asked for but select top cell, use Ctrl-Shift-End to go to last cell with content, use Shift-Left to adjust your column selection

Comment: For last row: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba) and then it's a matter of using something like `Range("A3:J" & lastrow).ClearContents` (see IBas response, I didn't refresh before commenting)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question using VBA Code you could try the following example:

```
Sub deleteSheetData()
    ' Definition of Variables
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("//worksheet name//")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    ' Clear Cell contents
    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A3:J" & LastRow).ClearContents
    End With
End Sub
```

If you need to clear data by referencing the table object rather than  targeting the sheet, I will edit my response. Hope it helps!

Comment: Not bad, but two tiny details: 1) The rows also 'belong' to the worksheet i.e. `.Rows.Count` is more accurate. 2.) Since you're using the *With* statement, `.Range("A3:J" & LastRow).ClearContents` or, without concatenation, `.Range("A3", .Cells(LastRow, "J")).ClearContents` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code u need my friend

```
Sub CLEAR_CELLS()
    ' Clear cells in column A from A3 to A1000
    Range("A3:A1000").Clear

    ' Clear cells in columns B to J from B1 to J1000
    Range("B1:J1000").Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: This is hardcoded and should be avoided if possible. You're also clearing possible headers in B1:J1 with this.

Answer (score 0):

### Clear Between Columns

[image]

```
Sub ClearBetweenColumns()
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FIRST_COLUMN_TOP_CELL As String = "A3"
    Const SECOND_COLUMN As String = "J"
    Const LAST_ROW_COLUMN As String = "J"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim fcell As Range: Set fcell = ws.Range(FIRST_COLUMN_TOP_CELL)
    
    Dim lcell As Range: Set lcell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, LAST_ROW_COLUMN) _
        .End(xlUp).EntireRow.Columns(SECOND_COLUMN)
    
    If lcell.Row < fcell.Row Then ' no data in last-row column
        MsgBox "The data had already been cleared!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ws.Range(fcell, lcell).ClearContents

    MsgBox "Data cleared.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Why `If lcell.Row < fcell.Row Then ... End If` ?**

- Once you have run the sub, the data in `J3:J1048576` is cleared.
- If you then run it once more, when the `.End(xlUp)` on column `J` is performed, the last cell will be cell `J2` (or even `J1`) and the data (headers?) in row `2` (rows `1` and `2`) will get **cleared without warning** because `A3:J2` (`A3:J1`) translates to `A2:J3` (`A1:J3`).